# Change log4j log level dynamically without configureAndWatch

Tags: tomcat, log4j

I know that, `configureAndWatch` is a handy way of changing log levels dynamically in a tomcat application. But instead of doing that, is there another way of doing it by configuring tomcat to log using `log4j`?

In apache [docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j), it says

> The steps described in this section are needed when you want to reconfigure Tomcat to use Apache log4j for its own logging. These steps are not needed if you just want to use log4j in your own web application.

But can't we use this same configuration to log our application logs? (I think if I put relevant jars and property file into lib folder will work. But i was unable get it right yet.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a servlet for change programmatically the level. e.g.:

```java
String logLevel = request.getParameter("level");
Logger root = Logger.getRootLogger();

if ("DEBUG".equalsIgnoreCase(level)) {
    root.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
} else if ("INFO".equalsIgnoreCase(level)) {
    root.setLevel(Level.INFO);
} else if ("WARN".equalsIgnoreCase(level)) {
    root.setLevel(Level.WARN);
} else if ("ERROR".equalsIgnoreCase(level)) {
    root.setLevel(Level.ERROR);
} else if ("FATAL".equalsIgnoreCase(level)) {
    root.setLevel(Level.FATAL);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Paul. But i would like to do it using tomcat configurations, rather than doing it programmatically.

Comment: I'm trying Paul, i was unable do it properly yet. There are some complications in my case. I'm using liferay tomcat and I want to use dailyRollingFileAppender. So that would be a another question separately. But if I can have a clear direction regarding this question, I think I can overcome those complications too.